# Drop Down Menu for Custom Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have been writing a wordpress theme from scratch and I have run into a problem with my top drop down menu. This drop down worked in html but didn't function once I brought everything into wordpress. Here is the code that I have inputed into my header.php

```
   <div class="nav">
        <ul >
          <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Nav Menu')); ?>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

For some reason none of my submenu items are populating and all of my main menu items are just stacked on top of each other in the left side of the page. Any help would be great

Comment: Try removing the `<ul>` and closing `</ul>` tags.

Comment: That didn't do anything

Comment: Weird. `wp_nav_menu()` encloses everything in a `<ul>`. Are the pages you are hoping to see in a dropdown child pages of a parent page?

Comment: Yes, I have set parent and child pages for some of them, but they aren't apprearing

Comment: Do you have a link I can take a look at?

Comment: The working CSS and HTML perhaps on jsfiddle?

Comment: I found out the problem was my jquerry was loading the wrong version because of a previous slider I was using. It is working fine now. Thanks